# Make an external DIY Fusion Drive

Tags: external-disk, fusion-drive

Last year, I created a Fusion Drive in my 13" MB (2008) by replacing the optical drive with a SSD and link it with the internal HDD by some terminal-magic from a computer magazine. It worked like a charm and was really fast.

Needing fast and big storage for video, I was thinking about creating an EXTERNAL Fusion Drive - preferably a HDD and a SDD within one enclosure - and connect it to the thunderbolt-port of my MBP.

Can this be done? Has anyone have experiences? A Google search didn't yield much information.

Comment: It's best to search for something (here or on google) and link to the best article you found. Explain how it doesn't make sense or answer your question. Then we can help you change your search or explain how the linked article needs improvement.

Comment: It make sense just in the same way an internal Fusion Drive makes sense: faster than an HD and more capacity than SSD. I am especially interested in this for a Mac Pro where you can't have an internal Fusion Drive. Also Google has no good results and if we had the answer we wouldn't come here.